# Overlay timestamps on many images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have 400 images like the following one:

[image]

I want to add timestamps for each image, so I will have 400 timestamps in total. Each timestamp contains hours, minutes and seconds ('HHMMSS').

For Image1 => Timestamp1 ... Image400 => Timestamp400.

I tried to use the following code:

```
for i = 1:400
     startDate = datenum('02-Nov-2013 13:30:06');
     endDate = datenum('02-Nov-2013 13:30:51');
     xdate = linspace(startDate,endDate,400);
     ... code to generate image
     set(gca,'XTick',xdate);
     datetick('x','HHMMSS');
end
```

But it became obvious that it didn't works, because I get the timestamps along an x axis, and I want a single timestamp for each image up to 400 images. Anyone has any clue how to do that?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to superimpose a textual timestamp on, say, the top left corner of each image ? Or do you want the timestamp as an `xlabel` ? Placing the timestamps in `XTick` makes no sense ...

Comment: I want to superimpose it on the top left corner or top right corner or top center of each image. So `XTick` makes no sense, correct. So I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Ok I'll post an answer later on today (I'm on my phone now) if no one's faster.

Comment: In the mean time, I will try some other stuff as well. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with [`datestr`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) and, most notably, [`insertText`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/inserttext.html) (from the *Computer Vision System Toolbox*) that does pretty much all the job:

```
% --- Get date list
startDate = datenum('02-Nov-2013 13:30:06');
endDate = datenum('02-Nov-2013 13:30:51');
xdate = linspace(startDate,endDate,400);

for i = 1:numel(xdate)

    % --- Code to generate image
    Img = imread('test.jpg');

    % --- Insert timestamp
    s = datestr(xdate(i), 'HH:MM:SS');

    Res = insertText(Img, [0 0], s, 'AnchorPoint','LeftTop', ...
        'BoxColor', 'white', 'fontsize', 40);

    % --- Display and break (to remove)
    imshow(Res)
    break;

end
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting. I am not at the office anymore, so I am not able to test the code. I am going to get back to you on Monday morning. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Everything works well. Thanks again for the help. Cheers